# How did Richard Rahl managed to turn Nicci to his side?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I am reading the *Wizard's First Rule* series for almost a decade now, at a slow pace.

The question I am asking is about what's happening on the 6th book, *Faith of the Fallen*, when

> Nicci is abducting Richard into the old world to show him that the way of the Imperial Order is the right one. However, she gets the opposite effect, when he is the one who convinces her that the Order is wrong.

I read this book about 3 years ago, and today I am back to reading the 9th book, *Chainfire*. The book reminds us many times about what happened in the 6th book and how Richard turned everything around, but I can't remember, and I am worried to search for it on the Internet and find spoilers.

What did Richard do specifically that managed to 'turn' Nicci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

**Nicci was awestruck by Richard's art, demonstrating his ideas.**

## Long answer

Nicci kidnapped Richard to make him understand the Order values. At the same time, she was fascinated by his integrity, and wanted to learn something from him, but did not get the grasp of it. Throughout the book, Richard showed Nicci that all the Order teachings<sup>*</sup> were a lie, and religion of the order worshiped death. By the end, he was ordered (by the Order priests) to carve a statue that was supposed to visually demonstrate those teachings. The job was done in secrecy, and nobody was supposed to see it until the end. Nicci realized that he was not carving what he was ordered to, as he looked as if he was going to finish the statue and die for it. She removed the cover to see the work, and it struck her numb.

<sub>**Faith Of The Fallen, Chapter 64**</sub>

> ...She felt as if a giant fist squeezed her heart to a stop.
>
> This was what was in Richard’s eyes, brought into existence in glowing white marble. To see it fully realized was like being struck by lightning.
>
> In that instant, her entire life, everything that had ever happened to her, everything she had ever seen, heard, or done, seemed to come together in one flash of emotional violence.
>
> Nicci cried out in pain at the beauty of it, and more so at the beauty of what it represented.
> Her eyes fell on the name carved in the stone base.
>
> **LIFE**
>
> Nicci collapsed to the floor in tears, in abject shame, in horror, in revulsion, in sudden blinding comprehension .
>
> . . . In pure joy.

- The Order doctrine stated that there is no purpose in life other than to help others selflessly, becoming a better person for the afterlife. Life was considered transient. Humans were portrayed as inadequate, sinful creatures, who were cleansed by the Light of the Creator. Since life was transient, nobody bothered to improve it, thus living in constant misery.

Comment: I remember now how it entertained me back then, how such an evil person saw a nice statue and got so excited that she decided 'ok I'll be good'. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: She wasn't really evil just lost sight of what the meaning of life was.  She was brainwashed to believe the Orders values were correct and living with Richard and seeing his master work made her realize the error in her ways.